# Manage float arrays on x86 assembly

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, x86

I'm trying to find the two less numbers of an array of floats in x86, but i don't know how to store the elements of the array

To access to an integer I use:

```
mov eax, 0            ; eax is a counter

mov ecx, vector       ; This store the vector on the register ecx
mov esi, [ecx+4*eax]  ; Stores the position eax of the vecor on esi
```

This work with an array of integers , but not with floats, I don't know how to do it. I checked putting 8 instead of 4 but it doesn't work

EDIT: When I say that it doesn't work, I mean that the values are not readed correctly, the number stored on

```
ESI is 1099956224 that is not correct
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on "it doesn't work." Where are they coming from and what are you doing with them? Note that in x86, floating-point values are usually not stored in general-purpose registers, but in the FPU registers/stack.

Comment: Take a look at the SSE instructions/registers...

Comment: 1099956224 is the IEEE-754 encoding for 18.0f.  That looks like a perfectly good floating point number to me.  Maybe you ought to load it into the FPU, maybe you ought to use a better debugger watch expression, it isn't very clear what you are going to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only compare floating point numbers if they in floating point registers. Trying to interpret a floating point number in memory as an integer is utterly pointless.

Read up on floating point support in x86. It's a whole different instruction set; historically, it used to be handled by a separate chip, one with an 87 model number. Specifically to load floats from memory, use the FLD command, to compare - FCOM*, to conditionally assign - FCMOV. Also, keep in mind the stack-y nature of the floating point subsystem.

EDIT: alternatively, you can use SSE scalar instructions. On a modern CPU, it may perform better than the legacy x87 instructions. Use MOVSS to load floats from memory and to copy between XMM registers, use COMISS to compare and set EFLAGS.

Finally, as Aki points out, floats in IEEE-754 format sort lexicographically; among two valid floats, the bit pattern of the larger one represents a larger integer, too. In real life, that's something you can leverage.

Comment: Except for the sign bit and NaNs, floating point numbers can be efficiently compared as integers.

Comment: That's right, but I think the point of this assignment is to make them learn FPU commands.